# How to python function of insert indexing

Tags: python, indexing

```
number = [1,2,3,4]

number[-1]

number.insert(-1,'last')

number[-1]

number[0]

number.insert(0,'first')

number[0]
```

Comment: Can you add a question to your question body?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and further help pages. Add a explanation to your code. Explain what is your goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insert at the first**

```
print(number)
number.insert(0,'first')
print(number)
```

You can see how it worked from the result following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
['first', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Insert at the last**
`-1` is indexing the front of the last of list items. So, The `insert` method put the item between `3` and `4`.
But, `append` does not need a number of index. Use `append`.

```
print(number)
number.append('last')
print(number)
```

You can see how it worked from the result following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'last']
```

Comment: @공대생코딩하는 You're welcome!. And, Please select the answer if the answer solves your question. and vote up if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a variable to the string or number you want to insert. Keep in mind that if you want to insert something at a specific index location in an array, it is best to use the `insert` function, `array.insert(index, variable)` because the `append` function can only insert a variable to the end of an array.

So, if say you wanted to add the string "last" to the end of your array, you could write this:

```
number = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = "last"
number.insert(len(number), x)
>>>number
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'last']
```

If you want to insert something at the first index, `[0]`, then just use `number.insert(0, variable)`. When someone is looking to insert variables into multiple index locations, it's best to simply use the `insert` function because mixing `insert` and `append` functions can make your code unreadable, or simply confusing. `append` is okay for a one time use, but if you're going to do like what you're asking, inserting things at multiple index locations, stick with `insert` for readability. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: I just switched -1 to 5, that was my mistake. It works perfectly now.

Comment: How about `number.insert(4, x)`, `number.insert(6, x)`, `number.insert(7, x)`...?

Comment: ...what about them?

Comment: This works because there are 4 elements. The same doesn't if there are say 10 elements.(Assuming OP is trying to insert at the end of list)

Comment: Obviously, you choose the number after the last in your array, or just use `number.insert(len(number), x)`...Are you trolling?

Comment: no I'm not a good troller. Just pointing things when there is more obvious `append()` to handle the case.

Comment: Append only works for when you want to add to the end of an array, while insert provides you any index option. The OP is asking how to insert at specific index locations, thus append will not work.

Comment: `append` is better for OP's question.

Comment: No it is not. `append` can only add to the end of the array, it cannot take index values. He asked how to insert variables at specific indexes of the array, thus you need `insert`. Please look up the Python docs, the two of you seem confused as to the difference between `append` and `insert`.